# Implementing AutoFill, Geolocation, and directions in Fusion Tables map

Tags: javascript, geolocation, google-fusion-tables, infowindow, autofill

I have a demo interactive map at http://northdakotarigsmap.com/new13 that I am close to figuring out. In it I have an autocomplete field querying a fusion table and upon selecting the queried value it should filter so only 1 of the placemarks shows up.
Only, the click event for the search field isn't doing anything.

I have a simpler example at http://northdakotarigsmap.com/GoogleExAndRigs that I have working but I can only get the default fusion table info window to work and I want a tabbed window and directions like I have on /new13.

I don't know what to do from here. I am admittedly a novice and I mostly just hack at the code until I get it to work, so I apologize for any ugliness ahead of time.

I have added an error handler that works (sort of) if denying geolocation. I like the geolocation code I have for both pages and the autofill but I don't know how to work the directions service and the custom infowindow like I have on /new13 (you have to accept geolocation at this point to see how the infowindow looks).

At the end of the day, what I need is a watchPosition type of geolocation that updates as the user moves, a custom infowindow that allows you to get directions from the users current position to the fusion table marker, and an auto filter for the fusion table that will filter only the requested marker on the table.

Comment: How is this question different from your [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674633/displaying-fusion-tables-autofill-results)? Maybe you can delete one of those (and edit the other one).

Comment: I clarified this one a bit better and the other one is deleted.